# Rationality of the representation of $(SL_2)^r$ arising from a $\mathbb{Q}$-VHS

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In the multivariable $SL_2$-orbit theorem (which describes the asymptotic behavior of the period map associated to a polarized $\mathbb{Q}$-VHS, can we choose a suitable base point such that the representation of $\mathbf{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})^r$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$? The answer for case of $r=1$ is yes and it was proved by Schmid in his famous 1973's paper.